How to download raw file content using nodejs express
I am currently trying to download a file from XERO intrgrated software I am getting the response from xero but I dont know how to save or download the raw file content. I am using the xero API documentaion from https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/attachments
I am getting the result in data like
\����[�����\u0012���\u0010����������="�\u001bֱ�\u0002��Kl�b��6\u0011�,�-��d\u0001�k��V�x�K�+\u0001q(\u0001\u0007NO'�]\u0018���\u0004)\u000e�\b#Ӓ��"��\u000f\u001b�=�u��\f�~%�o�K_�Me\u0005�r�F���"\u0012@�\u0003�k����\u0014\u001d�K�\u001bNK�\u0012\u0006�p0�\u001c\u0012{�\u0000���\u0012k��\u0006�\u0000)7\u0010�p1���yݗƯ�z׍o>\u0019i�<ҥ�/ښ�K\u0007�T��\u0010�4i��bzaI玼W�_X��n���(P�[\u0003�x�e\u0006�,�-�[H�v���3�<\u0006��O�eG/��ƣnǖ��=3ڼ��O�M�\u0007�>�k�߈�,����\u001bL֩\u001c�\u0012��\u0004�\u0002I��[\u0004�q���S�����.�U�-����.�j��w\u001a����\u0011��U{)Z�\u0003ׯa����+�u\u0003 �a�f�6��K�\u0007�\u0018\u0001\u0001<��\u000ekQ�6�_g��؁[\u0004���+俋������~�}\u000b]׎����\u0012{]"?���8m��b\u0004w~jaM�D���{9����o\u0000\f��=�����\u0000\u0005��ëo��[�\n�~�?\u0013��:j�|��%��$�əT1ʌ\u001c�{�տ\u0001i��_�m��i��Xio4�V���#mt����#\u0013�\u0001�,��q�dW��U=\u0016{?��J����&�l��6G#\u0002O�\u0004\u000fz��Ӕj% >I�\u0000�M���\u0011<l.e+��&+x����6�~�\t��Ƿ�u\u0012Rl�8N\u0006}?¿\u0007��>7�_ÿ\u0010x��~<ա�4m\u001fN�໶$����\u0012\u000f�܃¨$⾯��\u0000��|\u0012�Ԧ�/\fkw��/\u0012��r���� l�V��<�;�\u000b�?S�\u0015�ߖ�k�X\u0013Џ�s~.�ѼC��\u0011'�mD�]�\u0013-�2(xf��\u0016�2�����s�\u0006�9|���6���}P��[����d�ݾ�\u001c���\u0016\u0005��C�\u000e��tR�|0���C�\u0002\u0010s��>+�\u0011q�Lg�!�&�\u000f�Q�=0�C�\u0000\t\r�A�\u0004Y������p���H2�\u0019�6\u001c�\u000f�\u0000U.߲\u001a��F�;��\u0002\u000b�b�H�:\u0018����~��w��|9�O➩���\u001f\u000eu��R4�C\u0004\u0011]G�χ{\u001dѰ�\u000e}�\rw�(�s�@�m\u0002[çG)\fڀ\t��]ߨ��+m�4���Hw\u001ff��5�����)�\u001a��Þ\u0012��V�����m\u0003)�s\u001b�|��a�#���x\u0015���3����jm໯\u0017èI"N��c[@�\u0018�#�>\u0013'\u0019 \f�5���M&�\u0003�$���>j\u0006\
i dont know how to save this raw content in file.
I have tried following code
const response: any = await xeroService.downloadFileFromUrl(attachmentUrls, resAttachment?.xeroTokenInfo);
const writer = fs.createWriteStream('image.png');

response?.data?.pipe(writer);

res.send(response.data);


I am getting the result in data like you mean from the res.send(response.data);? Because yeah, displaying image data as text will not go that well. Or is this the content of the image.png file when you try to open it?

yes, it's a png file, please.

Mhm, kind of looks like when you open an image with a text editor, but additionally some characters are escaped as Unicode characters. You could check the Content-Type header of the request/response, should be either image/png or stream, but I think the first would be better. And is there a specific reason you use a writeStream? It's not like you are constantly receiving data but requesting a single file. Try to use fs.writeFile() or fs.write() instead.

What is xeroService?,  also if you want to use a stream twice, eg.  save to file and also res.send you will need to clone the stream, this package might help -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-stream-clone.  Also are you sure downloadFileFromUrl returns a stream and not a blob?, if it's a blob like @GreenSaiko says you could just use writeFile.
